# Save excel file in a folder that i opened 2 windows before

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, xaml

I opened a directory in 
window2:

```
private void CreateFolder()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\ben\Desktop\מחקר";
    string param = string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", UserFirstName.Text.ToString(), UserLastName.Text.ToString(), UserDate.Text.ToString());
    string finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, param);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(finalPath);
    Userpath.Text = finalPath;
}
```

Now, on the next window I created an excel file:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;
    oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)                                                                     (oXL.Workbooks.Add("")); 
    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
    oSheet.Range["A1"].Value = "Type";
    oSheet.Range["B1"].Value = "Time";
    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").VerticalAlignment =
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
    oWB.SaveAs(@"finalpath2.Text");
 }
```

finalpath2 is the same path as the finalpath on the previous window.
the goal is that the excel file will be saved inside the folder that I opened on window2. Can someone please help me?

Comment: i cant save the excel file in the directory that i opened a window before. its just save the excel file in a default directory with the name "finalpath2.text".

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the directory to the second window, or access the `UserPath` object in the second window to get the text out.

If they are two different windows, you can pass as an argument to the second window a string parameter which contains the directory path and then use that in your `oWB.SaveAs(filePath + @"/finalPath2.text");`

The other option, if the second window can access the `UserPath` object is to include it in your save as command like so `oWB.SaveAs(UserPath.Text + @"/finalPath2.text");`

Comment: this solution helps me to save the excel file in the main directory but i want to save it in the secondary folder that i opened in the previous window. any suggestions?

Comment: If `finalPath2` is the same directory as `finalPath` as in the first code snippet, then why is it in speech marks with `finalPath2` being passed as a string? Also, you have no file extension other than `.text` at the end of it, this would at best save a text file, not an Excel file. Try changing the save as function to something like:
`oWB.SaveAs(finalPath2 + @"/MyFileName.xlsx");`
Use `.xlsx` or similar to give it an Excel file extension.

Comment: doesn't work lol. it saves the file in path and not in final path.